# Large trainable embedding layer slows down training

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, word-embedding

I am training a network to classify text with a LSTM. I use a randomly initialized and trainable embedding layer for the word inputs. The network is trained with the Adam Optimizer and the words are fed into the network with a one-hot-encoding.

I noticed that the number of words which are represented in the embedding layer influences heavily the training time, but I don't understand why. Increasing the number of words in the network from 200'000 to 2'000'000 almost doubled the time for a training epoch.

Shouldn't the training only update weights which where used during the prediction of the current data point. Thus if my input sequence has always the same length, there should always happen the same number of updates, regardless of the size of the embedding layer.

Answer (score 1):

The number of updates needed would be reflected in the number of epochs it takes to reach a certain precision.

If your observation is that convergence takes the same number of epochs, but each epoch takes twice as much wall clock time, then it's an indication that simply performing the embedding lookup (and writing the update of embedding table) now takes a significant part of your training time.

Which could easily be the case. 2'000'000 words times 4 bytes per float32 times the length of your embedding vector (what is it? let's assume 200) is something like 1.6 gigabytes of data that needs to be touched every minibatch. You're also not saying how you're training this (CPU, GPU, what GPU) which has a meaningful impact on how this should turn out because of e.g. cache effects, as for CPU doing the exact same number of reads/writes in a slightly less cache-friendly manner (more sparsity) can easily double the execution time.

Also, your premise is a bit unusual. How much labeled data do you have that would have enough examples of the #2000000th rarest word to calculate a meaningful embedding directly? It's probably possible, but would be unusual, in pretty much all datasets, including very large ones, the #2000000th word would be a nonce and thus it'd be harmful to include it in trainable embeddings. The usual scenario would be to calculate large embeddings separately from large unlabeled data and use that as a fixed untrainable layer, and possibly concatenate them with small trainable embeddings from labeled data to capture things like domain-specific terminology.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborated answer! My training set consists by a large percentage of product names. I am training on a GPU. Why should the look-up in the memory matter if it is RAM? Doesn't look-up have O(1) no matter the size of the table?

Comment: @Jonas There are a lot of details other than O() that start to matter for "small" speed differences like doubling execution time. Table lookup speed is highly dependant on cache hit rate (at least for CPU, reading 100 items in a row is literally 100x faster than reading 100 random items), for GPU training the time to copy that gigabyte+ table from CPU to GPU and back is nontrivial (something like half a second might be plausible for your table), so suddenly it's very important to consider how often the training process moves the data between CPU and GPU, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your network takes one-hot vectors representing words to embeddings of some size embedding_size. Then the embeddings are fed as input to an LSTM. The trainable variables of the network are both those of the embedding layer and the LSTM itself.

You are correct regarding the update of the weights in the embedding layer. However, the number of weights in one LSTM cell depends on the size of the embedding. If you look for example at the equation for the forget gate of the t-th cell, 
[image: f_t = \sigma_g(W_f x_t + U_f h_{t-1} + b_f)]
you can see that the matrix of weights W_f is multiplied by the input x_t, meaning that one of the dimensions of W_f must be exactly embedding_size. So as embedding_size grows, so does the network size, so it takes longer to train.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have explained my approach in more details. I keep the dimension for one word the same, but increase the total number of words that exist in the embedding. I will update my question!

Comment: One possibility would be that the weights no longer fits in memory, and so you are waiting for tensorflow to read them from file.

Comment: I thought about this, too, but couldn't figure out a way to validate this. Do you know how I could see this memory problem?